# Check if a date is in range of lookup table

Tags: r, date, join, data.table, range

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

Data1 <- data.table(
  ID_a = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  ID_b = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  Date_1 = c("2018-01-01", "2018-05-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-09-01", "2018-10-01") %>% 
    as.Date
)
```

The two variables ID_a and ID_b are ID variables. Now I have another dataset that looks like this:

```
Data2 <- data.table(
  ID_a = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  ID_b = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  Date_start = c("2018-01-01", "2018-03-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-05-01", "2018-08-01") %>% 
    as.Date,
  Date_end = c("2018-02-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-06-01", "2018-08-01", "2018-10-01") %>% 
    as.Date
)
```

Now I want to check for each row of the first dataset if the date is in at least one of (!) the ranges between `Date_start` and `Date_end` with the same ID values of the second dataset. The output should look like this (the first one is TRUE because it's in the first range with `ID_a == 1` and `ID_b == 1`):

```
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE
```

Comment: you have 5 rows and your desired output is a vector of length 6. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Yes, sorry! One FALSE was too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
Data1[Data2
      , on = .(ID_a, ID_b, Date_1 >= Date_start, Date_1 <= Date_end)
      , test := between(x.Date_1, i.Date_start, i.Date_end)
      ][is.na(test), test := FALSE][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > Data1
>    ID_a ID_b     Date_1  test
> 1:    1    1 2018-01-01  TRUE
> 2:    1    1 2018-05-01 FALSE
> 3:    2    1 2018-07-01 FALSE
> 4:    1    2 2018-09-01 FALSE
> 5:    2    2 2018-10-01  TRUE
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `dplyr` -

```
left_join(Data1, Data2, by = c("ID_a", "ID_b")) %>%
  mutate(test = Date_1 >= Date_start & Date_1 <= Date_end) %>%
  group_by(ID_a, ID_b, Date_1) %>%
  summarise(test = any(test)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 x 4
   ID_a  ID_b Date_1     test 
  <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <lgl>
1    1.    1. 2018-01-01 TRUE 
2    1.    1. 2018-05-01 FALSE
3    1.    2. 2018-09-01 FALSE
4    2.    1. 2018-07-01 FALSE
5    2.    2. 2018-10-01 TRUE
```

Comment: It only gave me a "TRUE" but I know what you meant, great!
I did the same in data.table:
    Data1 <- merge(Data1, Data2, all = TRUE) %>% 
      .[, Test := Date_1 >= Date_start & Date_1 <= Date_end] %>% 
      .[, .(Test2 = any(Test)), .(Date_1, ID_a, ID_b)]